# text field keyup event is not firing

Tags: jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
 $('#code').keyup(function() {
    alert('aa');
});
});
</script>
```

this is the control to call the event

```
<input type='text' name='code' id='code' value=''>
```

this is my code but there is no alert box. I didn't get the reason.

Comment: Is your jQuery code within a document.ready call or at the end of the body?

Comment: within document.ready

Comment: If that were the case then it should work fine: http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/4uct5cxr/. Are you getting any errors?

Comment: no I didn't get any error. should it required any jquery plugin?

Comment: Nope, no plugins (other than jQuery) needed, as you can see by the fiddle I linked to.

Answer (score 0):

if thats how your code is structured, then the problem is that jquery did NOT find an element whose ID is code because the javascript code executed before the element make its way to the DOM. You should either do `$(){//your code}` or just put the JS code after the input element. P.S. And you are missing the close `/>` for your input element

Comment: Don't know if the question was edited before your answer, but looks like OP had put it inside `document.ready` so doesn't matter where his script is placed. Also, HTML5 does not require self-closing tags. Just pointing out. Cheers.

Comment: @philtune it was edited after my answer apparently. and tbh html is really forgiving when it comes to error checks. Though it might work doesnt mean it should be done